# Jquery-mobile messes up css background images on the iphone browser and UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

When I add the jquery-mobile javascript to my site some of the background css images fail to load until I go to a different page and come back to the home page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

The second I delete the import line, the images load fine. What might be the issue?

This issue only appears on the ios safari browser and a UIWebView. Works fine in a PC browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it was a jquery-mobile bug. Switching to the latest beta version did the trick for me:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
```